# javascript append at specific index document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to create a new element and insert it inside document.querySelector('.content'); at specific index? my simple code below.

```
const container = document.querySelector('.content');
var counter = 0;
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = "INSERT NEW"
var buttonOne = document.createElement('button');
buttonOne.className = "btnClass";
buttonOne.innerText = "Insert";
buttonOne.onclick =  function() {
    var buttonTwo = document.createElement('button');
    buttonTwo.className = "btnClass";
    buttonTwo.innerText = "new";
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('container').children);
    var index = nodes.indexOf(this);
    var c = document.createElement('p');
    c.textContent = "inserted new p";
    **container.append(c, buttonTwo, index++); <-- something like this**
};

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = "Index" + " " + i 
    container.append(p, buttonOne);
}
```

for example; if I have 10 buttons. Click on the 3rd, it should ADD a new element at 4th and pushes the rest.
is it possible? or any other options?

Comment: You may be interested in `document.querySelectorAll`, which returns an iterable converted to an array with `[...document.querySelectorAll(".content")]`. `[...document.getElementsByClassName("content")]` works as well.

Comment: Use Element.insertAdjacentHTML() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

Use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` could do the job for you.

> The insertAdjacentHTML() method of the Element interface parses the specified text as HTML or XML and inserts the resulting nodes into the DOM tree at a specified position.

I don't know how you really want to implement your code, but this is an example where I replace all your index `p` to `a` tag and when you press on any `button`, it will insert element after that specific element.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.content');
var counter = 0;
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.textContent = "INSERT NEW"
var buttonOne = document.createElement('button');
buttonOne.className = "btnClass";
buttonOne.innerText = "Insert";
buttonOne.onclick = function() {
  var buttonTwo = document.createElement('button');
  buttonTwo.className = "btnClass";
  buttonTwo.innerText = "new";
  var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('container').children);
  var index = nodes.indexOf(this);
  var c = document.createElement('p');
  c.textContent = "inserted new p";

};


for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var p = document.createElement('button');
  p.className = 'index'
  p.textContent = "Index" + " " + i
  container.append(p, buttonOne);
}
const allindex = document.querySelectorAll('.index')
allindex.forEach((i, index) => {
  i.addEventListener('click', () => {
    allindex[index].insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<button>newbutton</button>")
  })
})
```

```html
<div class='content'></div>
```